# PHP Parse Error Unexpected ';'

Tags: php

Heres the code.
Sorry if this is a bad question, I'm very new to PHP.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($searchsingle); $i++){
    if($yougender !== $searchsingle[$i] && $youOS = $searchsingle[$i+4] && $youmin >= 
        $searchsingle[$i + 5] && $youmax <= $searchsingle[$i + 6]{
Problem Line ----> $theirname = $searchsingle[$i - 1];
        $theirgender = $searchsingle[$i];
        $theirOS = $searchsingle[$i+4];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: Close, localised to a typo in the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing your closing parenthesis for the if statement:

```
if($yougender !== $searchsingle[$i] && $youOS = $searchsingle[$i+4] && $youmin >= 
    $searchsingle[$i + 5] && $youmax <= $searchsingle[$i + 6]{
```

should be

```
if($yougender !== $searchsingle[$i] && $youOS = $searchsingle[$i+4] && $youmin >= 
    $searchsingle[$i + 5] && $youmax <= $searchsingle[$i + 6]) { // <-- It goes there
```

Comment: You think after how long I've been looking at this, I would have noticed. Thank You.

Comment: @Corjava, try a code editor that highlights code and try to use a formatting that makes spotting such bugs easier ;)

Answer (score 0):

As @John said you were missing the parenthesis

Also I notice you have `$youOS = $searchsingle[$i+4]` which is an assignment not a comparison it should be `==`

To avoid mistakes like that use good syntax highlight like @luceos suggested

Personaly I hate long condition, break them down in smaller booleans something along the lines:

```
$search_gender = $yougender !== $searchsingle[$i];
$search_os =  $youOS == $searchsingle[$i+4];
$search_min = $youmin >= $searchsingle[$i + 5];
$search_max = $youmax <= $searchsingle[$i + 6];

if($search_gender && $search_os && $search_min && $search_max )
```